# Forward arguments of std::function given as an argument to new object

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Here is my problem: I would like to create a `std::function` object which will "extract" a part of its argument and pass that to a different `std::function` object.

I need a function like this:

```
std::function<void(Event)> MakeEventCallback(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Input>&)>);
```

Call to this potential function:

```
some_global_callbacks.push_back(MakeEventCallback(
  [](std::shared_ptr<Input>& input){ /*do stuff with input object;*/ input->DoStuff();}
));
```

`some_global_callbacks` is eventually processed like this:

```
auto event = createEvent(...);
for (auto eventCallback : some_global_callbacks)
{
  eventCallback(event);
}
```

The constructor of `Event` takes a `std::shared_ptr<Input>`, which can also be retrieved from the `Event` using `Event::getOriginalInput`.

I want the invocation of `eventCallback` to invoke the original `callback` passed to `MakeEventCallback` with the appropriate input.

Comment: I can't quite understand your question: There are not arguments contained in a `std::function` object. Arguments are passed to `std::function::operator()` at the time the stored function is invoked. Can you clarify what you're after?

Comment: I would like a lambda passed to my MakeEvent function to be invoked, and later on use the argument given in the lamba to return an Event object that takes the same type of argument in its constructor.

Comment: So does `MakeEvent` invoke the `std::function` passed in? If so, can it just re-use the same argument it provides to it? Can you perhaps show a bit more code?

Comment: Yes MakeEvent will invoke the std::function and re-use the same arguments provided to the std::function for its own purpose (aka, creating an Event object). I will try to type something more if Im still not clear. PS: the Input object can be a shared_ptr everywhere as well. I will update my code

Comment: But you cannot call `callback()` without arguments: the signature is `void callback(std::shared_ptr<Input>&)`. So just use the same argument for both.

Comment: Yes but basically I'd like the MakeEvent function to take this std::function, invoke it and forward its argument to the Event Object. I am just a bit unsure if it is possible to extract the argument out of the std::function to pass it elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136236/discussion-between-angew-and-trexgris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136236/discussion-between-angew-and-trexgris), I believe you're looking for this:

```
std::function<void(Event&)> MakeEventCallback(std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Input>&)> callback)
{
  return [callback](Event& ev) { callback(ev.getOriginalInput()); };
}
```

This will create a "wrapper" callback which takes an `Event`, extracts the `Input` from that `Event`, and passes the `Input` to the original `callback`.